# Prove that the diagonals of the inverse of $ (A^T A)$ are always positive.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a square matrix $A$, with linearly independent columns. Prove that the diagonals of $(A^T  A)^{-1}$ are always positive.

I've started trying to multiply out general matrices to see what happens, but I can't think of a clever short way to prove this.

Comment: DiagonalS? Or diagonal?

Comment: Hint: Recall that $(A^TA)^{-1} = A^{-1}(A^{-1})^T$ and that you can get the diagonal element $b_{kk}$ of any square matrix $B$ by computing $e_k^TBe_k$, where $e_k$ is the $k$-th unit vector.

Comment: by k-th unit vector does this mean the kth column of B?

Answer (score 1):

To get the entry of the product of two matrices ($AB=C$), you multiply a whole row times a whole column and add the products together:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ki}B_{ir}=c_{kr}$$
When $B = A^T$, the formula becomes:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ki}A_{ri}=c_{kr}$$
Because $A_{ij}^T=A_{ji}$, when getting the entries on the diagonal, $r=k$ and so you are adding squares of real numbers which are always non-negative, therefore $\mathrm {Tr} (C) \ge 0$.

 
This works because $(A^TA)^{-1}=A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}$ so you are essentially multiplying a matrix times its transpose.